# Calculate $\operatorname{Rad}(A/\operatorname{Rad}(A))$ in a Banach algebra

Tags: radicals, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $e_A$,  I'd like to find

> $\operatorname{Rad}(A/\operatorname{Rad}(A)).$

whre we define

> $\operatorname{Rad}(A)=\{a\in A:e_A-ba \in \text{InvA},b\in A\}$

I think it's equal $\operatorname{Rad}(A)$ but I don't khow how to prove that

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I presume you mean it is equal to the zero ideal of the quotient?

Comment: @Dear Pedro Tamaroff, you are right